# Tensorflow serving(docker): How to get the grpc request log sent by client?

Tags: grpc, tensorflow-serving

I've started tensorflow serving using docker:

```sh
docker run -d -p 8500:8500 -p 8501:8501 -p 8503:8503 \
    -v /tfserving/models:/models \
    -v /tfserving/config:/tfconfig \
    tensorflow/serving:1.14.0 \
    --model_config_file=/tfconfig/models.config \
    --monitoring_config_file=/tfconfig/monitor.config \
    --enable_batching=true \
    --batching_parameters_file=/tfconfig/batching.config \
    --model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds=30 \
    --file_system_poll_wait_seconds=30
    --rest_api_port=8503 \
    --allow_version_labels_for_unavailable_models=true
```

I can get the log by `docker logs containerid`, but only show the basic log:

```sh
2019-11-22 07:03:48.912930: I tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/saved_model_warmup.cc:103]
2019-11-22 07:03:48.938568: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:324] Running gRPC ModelServer at 0.0.0.0:8500 ...
[warn] getaddrinfo: address family for nodename not supported
2019-11-22 07:03:48.947993: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:344] Exporting HTTP/REST API at:localhost:8503 ...
[evhttp_server.cc : 239] RAW: Entering the event loop ...
```

When I sent grpc request from client, there aren't any more logs output.

And I'v tried to use the `-v=1` when starting, but it didn't work.

What I want to do is to get the grpc request log from server for problem solving. How to do with it? Thanks~